# Make postgresql database available to all user

Tags: postgresql

While accesing postgres database i got an error saying

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

to resolve this error i need to change the database owner like

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname OWNER TO 'all';
```

all is not a user in my system, but i want to make this database available to all the user in the system.

I am sure there is way to do stuff like this. can any one help me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to [read the Client Authentication section of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html), particularly the part that discusses `pg_hba.conf`. PostgreSQL's manual and tutorials are fairly comprehensive and are well worth a read.

There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow, superuser.com, serverfault.com and dba.stackexchange.com that cover `pg_hba.conf` so I won't repeat what's already available in abundance.

Very short version:

- Use `md5` authentication; and
- `CREATE USER` all the users you want to be able to log in or have them all log in as a shared identity.

*Please* read the manual sections on authentication and security to avoid future pain and problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your file system find pg_hba.conf file using

```
locate pg_hba.conf
```

Then find the version of your postgres.

edit the file using

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

If you have the following line:

```
local   all    all     peer
```

then change it to:

```
local   all    all     md5
```

I am sure it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Peer authentication means that PostgreSQL will only allow the OS user, `admin`, to connect as `admin`, or the OS user `myuser` to connect to PostgreSQL as `myuser`.

This is because it has an entry in the `pg_hba.conf` file like this

```
local   all    all    peer
```

If you replace it with this

```
local   all   all    trust
```

then all users on the same OS that hosts the PostgreSQL database will be able to connect freely.